# Create a list from imported JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I try to create a dynamic list from a imported JSON file and keep getting error"XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource." and the file doesn't load. Could someone help to give some hint. Thx!

This is my js file

```
$.getJSON( "recordingList.json", function( data ) {
    var values = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= values.length; i++) {
        var value = values[i];
        var element = $($('#template').html());
        element.find('.date').html(value.date);
        element.find('.lan').html(value.lan);
        element.find('.topic').html(value.topic);
        element.find('.speaker').html(value.speaker);
        element.find('.play').attr('href', value.play);
        element.find('.download').attr('href', value.link);
        $('.list').append(element);
    };
});
```

HTML file

```
<ul class="list">
    <script type = "text/template" id="template">
    <li class='list-item'>
    <span class='date'></span>
    <span class='lan'></span>
    <span class='topic'></span>
    <span class='speaker'></span>
    <a class ='play' title='Listen' href=""><i class='fa fa-play-circle-o'></i></a>
    <a class ='download' title='Download' href=""><i class='fa fa-download'></i></a>
    </li>
    </script>
</ul>
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for `$.getJSON(...)` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ - the first parameter is an URL... you are passing the name of a file but is it at the correct location ?(i.e. is your file located at the same level as the HTML file?)

Comment: I swap the file path to absolute url. The error is gone. Thx! Now I'm still trying to figure how to push the date into the dynamic list

Answer (score 0):

Change your URL to the correct URL which points to the file recordingList.json

after then inorder to append the data in the list you can use simple string concatenation and afterwards appending the string in the `<ul>`

```
$.getJSON( "whatever/recordingList.json", function( data ) {
for (var i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
  var value = data[i];
  _html = "<li class='list-item'>"
    +"<span class='date'>"+value.date+"</span>"
    +"<span class='lan'>"+value.lan+"</span>"
    +"<span class='topic'>"+value.topic+"</span>"
    +"<span class='speaker'>"+value.speaker+"</span>"
    +"<a class ='play' title='Listen' href='"+value.play+"'><i class='fa fa-play-circle-o'></i></a>"
    +"<a class ='download' title='Download' href='"+value.link+"'><i class='fa fa-download'></i></a>"
    +"</li>";
    $('.list').append(_html);
    }
});
```